# Export data from MySQL using phpMyAdmin is not streaming anymore

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export a large database from MySQL 5.7.22 using phpMyAdmin 4.8.2 export tab. When I click on "go" (to download), the request takes a long time to receive a response from the server when the data is large. The download essentially doesn't stream, the server tries to package the entire data and send it back. If the data is large, the download request times out at 5 min.

With phpMyAdmin 4.7.9, this was not an issue. The download used to stream and work fine. There was no timeout because of no response, since it was streaming.

Is this a behavior change in the new phpMyAdmin? Is there a configuration I can change to make streaming data on export work for 4.8.2? Or is this a MySQL issue? (We recently updated to MySQL 5.7.22)

P.S: I have to use phpMyAdmin due to some constraints, so other solutions will not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've rarely seen such a well-written first post. I hope you get a useful response.

Comment: It's not clear whether this was opened by you, but a day before your post here someone asked a very similar question in the phpMyAdmin issue tracker: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14478; if it wasn't you I suggest you follow the discussion there.